# JMeter - RegEx Extractor seems correct but request header has ${token} instead of value

Tags: variables, jmeter, http-headers

## Set-up

### Request #1

`POST https://url/`

#### RegEx Extractor

[image]

### Response #1

```
{
 "Token":"WkQTxNnZRR0nofyJzb-kioALlXgwc7cN9rokXrKzWmtB2BDedUXeQnd94S5KWvaz0",
 "ExpirationUTC":"2121-09-17T14:39:57.504Z",
 "TokenId":"string"
}
```

### Request #2

`GET https://some-other-url`

#### Header Manager

As shown:
[image]

## Result

Instead of
`Authorization: Bearer WkQTxNnZRR0nofyJzb-kioALlXgwc7cN9rokXrKzWmtB2BDedUXeQnd94S5KWvaz0`
we have
`Authorization: Bearer ${token}`

[image]

## Debug Component Results - Starting to Look Like a Variable Scope Issue

[image]
... but:
[image]

## Result of RegExp Tester

Here, I used the same reg-ex as I used in the Reg Ex Extractor, and it finds the desired string.

[image]

## JSON Extractor Attempt

[image]

Still says `Bearer ${token}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `Variables are local to a thread` hence you cannot refer the variables which are set in one Thread Group in another Thread Group.

You either need to convert the variable into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in 1st thread group and load it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd thread group or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Also be informed that [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions is not the best choice for extracting the token from the response